# How to get count = 0 if column does not appear in group by multiple fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find average number of events people attended by days.

There is a table "user_event" like this:

```
user_id | event_id | day 
---------+----------+-----
       1 |  CONCERT |   1 
       1 |     SHOW |   1 
       1 |      TED |   2 
       1 |  CONCERT |   2 
      20 |     SHOW |   1 
      20 |      TED |   1 
      20 |      TED |   2 
      20 |     SHOW |   3 
     300 |  CONCERT |   1 
     300 |  CONCERT |   3 
     300 |     SHOW |   3
```

As you can see, user[300] didn't attend any event on day[2], user[1] didn't attend any event on day[3].

First I want is to write this:

```
select count(*), user_id, day from user_event group by user_id, day;
```

and get

```
 count | user_id | day 
-------+---------+---- 
     2 |       1 |  1 
     2 |       1 |  2 
     0 |       1 |  3 
     2 |      20 |  1 
     1 |      20 |  2 
     1 |      20 |  3 
     1 |     300 |  1 
     0 |     300 |  2 
     2 |     300 |  3
```

Next step would be:

```
select avg(count) from --window function of first step--
```

with results:

```
  avg | day 
------+---- 
 1.66 |  1 
    1 |  2 
    1 |  3
```

---

First question is how to get zero count if an user didn't attend any event on some day?

Second one. Is it possible to aggregate it without window function?

Thank you!

Comment: *"Is it possible to aggregate it without window function?"* There are *no* window functions here. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join`/`group by` for the calculation:

```
select u.user_id, d.day, count(ue.user_id)
from (select distinct user_id from user_event) u cross join
     (select distinct day from user_event) d left join
     user_event ue
     on ue.user_id = u.user_id and ue.day = d.day
group by u.user_id, d.day;
```

If you have other tables that have the list of days or user_ids, then use those.  Also, if you want a specific list of days, then you might want to use `generate_series()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using coalesce() and left join

```
select coalesce(count(*),0)
  , user_id
  , day 
from (
  select distinct user_id from user_event
) t
left  join user_event on t.user_id = user_event.user_id 
group by user_id, day;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option (especially for readability) is a couple of CTEs, you can join a distinct list of users to a series of generated integers and then left join that to you user_events table. This will give you a list with rows added for the days that they user did not go to an event. Something like this:

```
WITH core AS (

     SELECT * 
       FROM (SELECT generate_series(1,100) AS DAY) AS series
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_event) AS users ON TRUE

), day_sum AS (

     SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ue.day IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS events_per_day,
            ue.user_id,
            ue.day
       FROM core c
  LEFT JOIN user_event ue ON ue.user_id = c.user_id AND ue.day = c.day
   GROUP BY ue.day, ue.user_id

)

     SELECT AVG(events_per_day)
       FROM day_sum AS ds
   GROUP BY ds.day
```